# Indigo on Ubuntu14.04 problem;point 1.3 set up your keys means?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , I stuckup while installing Indigo.  I did as per installation guidelines as shown in below link: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

I really did not understand guideline in "1.3 Set up your keys" . There is no proper explanation for this point. So I skipped this instruction and tried to proceeded with guideline "1.4 Installation" .

while installation I got this error :

admin51@admin51-ThinkPad-X201:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Based on the response from terminal. What could be the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190100/indigo-on-ubuntu14.04-problem;point-1.3-set-up-your-keys-means?/) by [omc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20008/omc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-13

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [1.3 step](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#indigo.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Set_up_your_keys) is referring to setting up keys for authenticating packages with the `apt-get` package manager using the [apt-key utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/apt-key.8.html). Basically if you skip this step, then every time you try and install ROS packages, your system will ask you if it's okay to install untrusted packages.

The error you placed in the question is likely completely unrelated. Apt-get (as well as aptitude, dpkg, synaptic, and likely others) use a "lock" system to ensure that the package manager can't be started if there is already an instance running (to avoid conflicting operations happening at the same time). Steps to try and fix the error:

1. Try running your command again without doing anything. Perhaps the process that originally caused your error is now finished.
2. If that doesn't work, there could be other instances of `apt-get` running that you are unaware of, or some program using the lock that you don't realize (like the Ubuntu software center). Try rebooting the computer and then try the command again. Or could also try the command `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` that could tell you if there is a process running that is using the lock file. If there is, you should see a printout telling you what the `PID` of the process is. You could manually kill this process using `kill -9 PID`.
3. If you are still getting the same error message, there could be something wrong with the lock file itself. If you get to this step, the fixes are slightly more drastic. Edit your original post, and let us know that the above things did not work.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20008/omc/) on 2014-08-14**:
thanks a lot it working now

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error message tells you the problem::

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

You have something else holding the dpkg lock running. (Possibly synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center)

Note skipping a step because you don't know what it does will usually make things fail. Once you resolve the problem of something else having the dpkg lock, you will not be able to install packages without the key in your keyring, provided by step 1.3.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2